# Why are ceilf32 and sqrtf32 unsafe?

Tags: rust

I'm pretty new to Rust and have been working on some mathematical problems. For one of these problems I needed `ceilf32` and `sqrtf32`. I was surprised to find that these functions are `unsafe`; both are fairly simple mathematical functions and my understanding is that unsafe Rust is used only as necessary to work around either the conservatism of the compiler or to allow inherently unsafe OS operations. I can't see any reason either function would run into either issue, thus I can't understand what would stop them being implemented with memory safety.

Could someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The functions you're looking at are in [`core::intrinsics`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/intrinsics/index.html), which are low-level compiler instructions. I don't see any *official* documentation on why they're marked `unsafe`, but my guess is that all of the compiler intrinsics were marked that way as a rule, since they're lower-level than most of Rust proper.

Regardless, for normal operation, you're looking for the inherent methods [`f32::ceil`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.ceil) and [`f32::sqrt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.sqrt). These are the Rust standard library implementations that presumably<sup>[1]</sup> call the intrinsics as a course of action, and *these* methods are not marked `unsafe`.

Since they're inherent methods, you can either call them on `f32` objects (`my_number.sqrt()`) or directly with the namespace (`f32::sqrt(my_number)`).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> In fact, a look at the [source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/f32.rs.html#362-364) [code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/f32.rs.html#68-70) for the current implementations indicates that both of these simply delegate to their intrinsic counterpart, wrapping it in an `unsafe` block to guarantee safety.

Comment: Some intrinsics are unsafe, some are not. I don't know if there is a rule, probably not.